# HTML Collapsible Button - How to make div appear after button?

Tags: html, css, web

I am trying to make a collapsible button with pure HTML and CSS. Here is what I have:

```css
#hidden {
  display: none;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

 :checked+#hidden {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="my_checkbox" style="display:none;">
<div id="hidden"></div>
<label for="my_checkbox">Show/hide</label>
```

This works. However, I want the hidden div to come *after* the button instead of before. When I move the div to after the checkbox label, it does not work.

How can I fix this ?

Thanks!

Comment: simply move the label before the input

Comment: Before the INPUT ... ah ok. Kind of counter-intuitive, but it works. Thanks!

Comment: why conter intuitive? it's simply logical ...what you have done is somehow strange, why you put the label after?

Comment: Putting the label before the input could be considered a good practice, however, the problem is that you can't reorder the elements very easily given the CSS selector that was chosen. I would go with a more flexible approach by using a more general combinator (see my answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use a different CSS selector. The below uses the [General sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) to target the `div` no matter its order with respect to the `input` element (so long as it follows it).

```css
#hidden {
  display: none;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

:checked ~ #hidden {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="my_checkbox" style="display:none;">
<label for="my_checkbox">Show/hide</label>
<div id="hidden"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

use negation instead of +, so that it will select all divs related to that class name

```css
#hidden {
  display: none;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

 :checked~#hidden {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="my_checkbox" style="display:none;">
<label for="my_checkbox">Show/hide</label>
<div id="hidden"></div>
```