# HTML Collapsible Button - How to highlight the button as href?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to create a collapsible button for my academic website, and found the answer to this question very helpful: [HTML Collapsible Button - How to make div appear after button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51841210/html-collapsible-button-how-to-make-div-appear-after-button). So I followed the answer and wrote the following code:

```css
#hidden {
  display: none;
}

:checked~#hidden {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="my_checkbox" style="display:none;"> My paper title. 
<label for="my_checkbox">Abstract</label>
<div id="hidden">this is my abstract.</div>
```

This worked, but I want to highlight the button "Abstract" like href so that we see it's clickable. How should I edit the css to make the button appears as href?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the same styles as an `a` tag using `color: blue` and `text-decoration: underline` with the selector `:hover`:

```css
label {
  color: blue;
}

label:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#hidden {
  display: none;
}

:checked~#hidden {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="my_checkbox" style="display:none;"> My paper title. 
<label for="my_checkbox">Abstract</label>
<div id="hidden">this is my abstract.</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Could I add 2nd paper? Now it opens both abstracts.
`label {
  color: blue;
}

label:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#hidden {
  display: none;
}

:checked~#hidden {
  display: block;
}`


`<input type="checkbox" id="my_checkbox" style="display:none;">1st paper title. 
<label for="my_checkbox">Abstract</label>
<div id="hidden">1st abstract</div>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="my_checkbox2" style="display:none;">2nd paper title. 
<label for="my_checkbox2">Abstract</label>
<div id="hidden">2nd abstract</div>`

Comment: @YukiTakahashi Please open a new question and I would be happy to answer it ;)