# HTML Collapsible Button - How to highlight the button as href (multiple buttons)?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to create a collapsible button highlighted as href for my academic website, and got an answer here: [HTML Collapsible Button - How to highlight the button as href?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61160374/html-collapsible-button-how-to-highlight-the-button-as-href)

However, when I create more than one buttons, the top button opens all the hidden texts (please see my code below). Could I modify the code so that each button only opens the hidden text just below it, or opens a specified hidden text?

CSS:

```
label {
  color: blue;
}

label:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer; }

#hidden {
  display: none;
}

:checked~#hidden {
  display: block;
}
```

Html:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="my_checkbox" style="display:none;">1st paper title.
<label for="my_checkbox">Abstract</label>
<div id="hidden">1st abstract</div>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="my_checkbox2" style="display:none;">2nd paper title.
<label for="my_checkbox2">Abstract</label>
<div id="hidden">2nd abstract</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same id can be used one time per page. So we have to use `class` instead of `id`. Also we should use [Adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) instead of [General sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator)

```css
label {
  color: blue;
}

label:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer; }

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

input:checked+label+.hidden {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="my_checkbox" style="display:none;">1st paper title.
<label for="my_checkbox">Abstract</label>
<div class="hidden">1st abstract</div>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="my_checkbox2" style="display:none;">2nd paper title.
<label for="my_checkbox2">Abstract</label>
<div class="hidden">2nd abstract</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, provided the HTML structure is reliable and consistent.

Change:

```
:checked~#hidden {
  display: block;
}
```

to

```
:checked + label + #hidden {
  display: block;
}
```

However, you can't have multiple items with the same `id` attriubte - use a class instead.